# DotCover - Excluding multiple assemblies via XML config

Tags: jetbrains-ide, dotcover

I am trying to exclude multiple assemblies from our CI coverage results. I am finding this difficult using the xml config suggested:

```
<Filters>   
<ExcludeFilters>
<FilterEntry>
<ModuleMask>*.Tests*</ModuleMask>
<ModuleMask>*.Client*</ModuleMask>
</FilterEntry>
</ExcludeFilters>
</Filters>
```

also I have tried this:

```
<Filters>
<ExcludeFilters>
<FilterEntry>
<ModuleMask>*Tests.*</ModuleMask>
<ClassMask>*</ClassMask>
<FunctionMask>*</FunctionMask>
</FilterEntry>
<FilterEntry>
<ModuleMask>*Client.*</ModuleMask>
<ClassMask>*</ClassMask>
<FunctionMask>*</FunctionMask>
</FilterEntry>
</ExcludeFilters>
</Filters>
```

This does not exclude the client and test assemblies as desired.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
H

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following example

```
<ExcludeFilters>
<FilterEntry>
 <ModuleMask>*.Test*</ModuleMask>   
</FilterEntry>
<FilterEntry>
    <ModuleMask>*Courses.Persistence*</ModuleMask> 
</FilterEntry>  
<FilterEntry>
    <ModuleMask>*Courses.ServiceContract*</ModuleMask> 
</FilterEntry>  
<FilterEntry>
    <ModuleMask>*.Courses.Domain*</ModuleMask> 
</FilterEntry>  
</ExcludeFilters>
```